# Разобраться почему не работает клиент

Tags: c#, wcf

Алгоритм распараллеливает вычисление интеграла по сети и отдельно на клиентах по потокам. Запускаю для теста сервер и два клиента. Один клиент отрабатывает, а второй просто висит. Он подключился в connectedClients его видно, но в workingClients его нет. И на сервере вместо результата в конце мне выводится "Очередь пуста.". Это при том что у меня везде где делается Dequeue стоят проверки на пустоту очереди. Зато если я запускаю чисто одного клиента то он отрабатывает нормально и результат на сервере выводится. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста! Вот ссылка на репозиторий с кодом: https://github.com/DarkByte2015/lab3.

Ну вот по просьбам трудящихся код в тему (только я так и не понял как тут его форматированным вставлять, если есть у кого модераторские полномочия поправьте)

TaskService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Timers;

namespace lab3_Server
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Описывает контракт сервиса.
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class TaskService : ITaskService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Список контрактов обратного вызова всех подключенных клиентов.
        /// </summary>
        private List<IClientCallback> connectedClients = new List<IClientCallback>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Список представлений работающих клиентов.
        /// </summary>
        private List<ClientView> workingClients = new List<ClientView>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Очередь еще не выполненных задач.
        /// </summary>
        private Queue<ClientTask> tasks = new Queue<ClientTask>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Список результатов.
        /// </summary>
        private List<double> results = new List<double>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Вызывается при присоединении клиента к серверу.
        /// </summary>
        public void Connect()
        {
            /// При присоединении нового клиента - 
            /// добавляем его в список подключенных клиентов.

            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();
            connectedClients.Add(callback);

            /// Если в очереди есть невыполненные задачи -
            /// берем задачу на выполнение.
            if (tasks.Count > 0)
                AddWorkingClient(callback);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Решает заданную пользователем задачу.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bottom"></param>
        /// <param name="top"></param>
        /// <param name="step"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double Solve(double bottom, double top, double step)
        {
            /// Формируем очередь задач.

            const double taskStep = 1.0;            

            for (var x = bottom; x < top; x += taskStep + step)
            {
                var task = new ClientTask(x, x + taskStep, step);
                tasks.Enqueue(task);
            }

            var tasksCount = tasks.Count;

            /// Рассылаем задачи подключенным клиентам.

            for (var i = 0; i < connectedClients.Count; i++)
                AddWorkingClient(connectedClients[i]);

            /// Ждем в цикле пока количество результатов в списке 
            /// не станет равно изначальному количеству задач, 
            /// после чего возвращаем их сумму.

            while (results.Count != tasksCount) ;

            return results.Sum();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавляет работающего клиента с задачей из очереди.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="callback"></param>
        private void AddWorkingClient(IClientCallback callback)
        {
            var client = new ClientView(callback, tasks.Dequeue());
            client.Calculated += Client_OnCalculated;
            client.Disconnected += Client_OnDisconnected;
            workingClients.Add(client);
            client.Calculate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вызывается после подсчета клиентом результата.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="result"></param>
        private void Client_OnCalculated(ClientView sender, double result)
        {
            /// Добавляем результат в список.

            results.Add(result);

            /// Если в очереди еще есть задачи - 
            /// берем задачу на выполнение,
            /// иначе удаляем клиента из работающих.

            if (tasks.Count > 0)
            {
                sender.Task = tasks.Dequeue();
                sender.Calculate();
            }
            else
                workingClients.Remove(sender);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вызывается при отключении клиента.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        private void Client_OnDisconnected(ClientView sender, Exception error)
        {
            /// Возвращаем задачу в очередь и 
            /// удаляем клиента из обоих списков.

            tasks.Enqueue(sender.Task);
            workingClients.Remove(sender);
            connectedClients.Remove(sender.Callback);
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);       
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вызывается при отключении клиента.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="result"></param>
        void ITaskService.SetResult(double result)
        {
            /// Переадресовываем результат клиенту.

            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();
            var client = workingClients.Find(c => c.Callback == callback);
            client.OnSetResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

ClientView.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace lab3_Server
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Описывает представление клиента.
    /// </summary>
    class ClientView
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Представляет метод, который будет обрабатывать событие Calculated.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="result"></param>
        public delegate void CalculatedHandler(ClientView sender, double result);

        /// <summary>
        /// Представляет метод, который будет обрабатывать событие Disconnected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        public delegate void DisconnectedHandler(ClientView sender, Exception error);

        /// <summary>
        /// Происходит при получении результата.
        /// </summary>
        public event CalculatedHandler Calculated;

        /// <summary>
        /// Происходит при отключении клиента.
        /// </summary>
        public event DisconnectedHandler Disconnected;

        /// <summary>
        /// Контракт обратного вызова клиента.
        /// </summary>
        public IClientCallback Callback { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Задание, которое клиент выполняет в данный момент.
        /// </summary>
        public ClientTask Task { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Таймер, определяющий задержку возврата результата.
        /// </summary>
        private Timer timer = new Timer(5000) { AutoReset = false };

        /// <summary>
        /// Определяет был ли возвращен результат.
        /// </summary>
        private bool returned = false;

        public ClientView(IClientCallback callback, ClientTask task)
        {
            Callback = callback;
            Task = task;
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Выдает задание.
        /// </summary>
        public void Calculate()
        {
            returned = false;
            timer.Enabled = true;

            try
            {
                Callback.OnGiveTask(Task);
                //Console.WriteLine("Give task success!");
            }

            /// Если произошла ошибка передачи задания - значит клиент отключился.

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Disconnected?.Invoke(this, e);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вызывается при получении результата.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="result"></param>
        public void OnSetResult(double result)
        {
            returned = true;
            timer.Enabled = false;
            Calculated?.Invoke(this, result);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Обработчик таймера.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// Если результат не вернули за истекшее время -
            /// считаем что клиент отключился.

            if (!returned)
                Disconnected?.Invoke(this, new TimeoutException("The client has not returned a result within a set time."));
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs клиента без кода интегрирования

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Прокси-сервис.
    /// </summary>
    static TaskServiceClient proxy = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Список результатов.
    /// </summary>
    static ConcurrentBag<double> results = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            /// Создаем калбэк, подключаем обработчики, создаем и подключаем прокси.

            var callback = new ClientCallback();
            callback.GiveTask += Callback_OnGiveTask;
            var ctx = new InstanceContext(callback);
            proxy = new TaskServiceClient(ctx);
            proxy.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вызывается при получении задания.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task"></param>
    private static void Callback_OnGiveTask(ClientTask task)
    {
        /// Распределяем задачу по потокам и 
        /// дождавшись их завершения выводим результат. 

        try
        {
            results = new ConcurrentBag<double>();
            var threadCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            var threadStep = (task.Top - task.Bottom) / threadCount;
            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            var x = task.Bottom;

            for (var i = 0; i < threadCount; i++, x += threadStep + task.Step)
            {
                var threadTask = new ClientTask()
                {
                    Bottom = x,
                    Top = x + threadStep,
                    Step = task.Step
                };

                var thread = new Thread(ThreadHandler);
                threads.Add(thread);
                thread.Start(threadTask);
            }

            threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());

            var result = results.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine("bottom: {0} top: {1} step: {2} result: {3}", task.Bottom, task.Top, task.Step, result);
            proxy.SetResult(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Это на мой взгляд самое основное.

Comment: Пожалуйста, выбросите из кода ту часть, которая не имеет отношения к самой проблеме (код вычисления интеграла) и приведите основу кода прямо в теле вопроса.

Comment: Но вы же сами понимаете основная часть сервиса - это как раз сам сервис. К решению интеграла там относятся считаные 1-2 функции в Program.cs клиента. Все остальное это контракты. Если я тут все это выложу тема раздуется на несколько страниц. :D На гитхабе все вполне удобно читать.

Comment: На гитхабе удобно читать, но послезавтра вы закроете свой репозиторий, и вопрос превратится в пустышку. Поэтому правила требуют [минимального воспроизводимого примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) прямо в теле вопроса. Контракты приводить не обязательно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `OnGiveTask();` у вас - синхронный. Это блокирует второго клиента от получения задачи на время, пока не отработает первый. И в целом вызывает непредсказуемые делдлоки при попытке выдать задачу в момент подключения клиента.

Вынесите вызов клиента в фоновый поток:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    Callback.OnGiveTask(Task)
);
```

- замените используемые коллекции на потокобезопасные - и все заработает.

Comment: Вроде бы WCF уже поддерживает async-интерфейсы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38276/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash-----).